# rootElement->FindFirst(...) fails to find element seen by Inspect

Tags: c++, windows, microsoft-ui-automation

I'm trying to locate a list item contained within the Services window (Start->Run->Services.msc) on Windows. The list item is named "Arc Service" and is easily found using Inspect, but my code fails to locate it. This being a relatively simple case, I feel I must be doing something wrong.

The code in question is:

```
VARIANT arcServiceNameVariant;
VariantInit(&arcServiceNameVariant);
arcServiceNameVariant.vt = VT_BSTR;
arcServiceNameVariant.bstrVal = L"Arc Service";

CComPtr<IUIAutomationCondition> arcServiceNameCondition;
hr = g_pAutomation->CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, arcServiceNameVariant, &arcServiceNameCondition.p);

if(SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    CComPtr<IUIAutomationElement> arcServiceElement;
    hr = rootElement->FindFirst(TreeScope_Descendants, arcServiceNameCondition, &arcServiceElement.p);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        if(arcServiceElement.p) {
            logInfo(L"Arc Service element found!");
        }
    } else {
        logInfo(L"FindFirst failed!");
    }
} else {
    logInfo(L"Failed to create property condition!");
}
```

The "Arc Service element found!" branch is never entered.

Here are the details from Inspect describing the element:

[image: MS Inspect Details]

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizzically it turns out that running my UIA client as Administrator sees the component, but running as the logged in user does not. For now I can elevate my process, but I'll continue to research the issue for a more detailed explanation.